# Search ignoring certain blank parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a simple search action that has 3 parameters and a where method to search a model. If I search and some of the parameters are nil, it will not return the records I want. I want it to search the database by only using the parameters that are not nil/blank. So if only one category is entered and sent in the parameters, I want my controller to ignore the other two parameters. However, if the other parameters are present, I want them to be included in the search.

I've tried many approaches but I can't get it to work properly. Here's my code.

```
hash = []
cat = :category_id => params[:category_id]
col = :color_id => params[:color_id]
brand = :brand_id => params[:brand_id]

if params[:category_id].present?
  hash += cat
end

if params[:color_id].present?
  hash += col
end

if params[:brand_id].present?
  hash += brand
end

@results = Piece.where(hash).preload(:item).preload(:user).group(:item_id).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9)
```

I've put the variables into strings and hashs, called to_a, joined them with (","). Nothing works.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
criteria = { :category_id => params[:category_id], :color_id => params[:color_id],
  :brand_id => params[:brand_id] }.select { |key,value| value.present? }


@results = Piece.where(criteria).preload(:item).preload(:user).group(:item_id).
  paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 9)
```

Comment: Exactly what I sought and so beautifully small :)